# Generate cluster field for a set of records which match the condition(s) using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, match

I have a table in PostgreSQL 9.4, with the following fields ID (primary key), Customer_Name, Mobile, Email. The ID column is unique for the record however not necessarily identifies a unique individual. A Customer can have multiple records with variations in name and/or different mobile or email, each time linked with a unique ID.

I have a requirement where I need a new calculated column (using a SQL query) with the name Cluster_ID which will uniquely identifies a customer based on matching of either Name OR Mobile OR Email, i.e. if either of name, mobile or email of one record matches with the other record, then those records should be assigned the same Cluster_ID. This Cluster_ID should be unique for the set of matching records and preferably same each time the query is executed.

I have created a sample DDL for Postgres (which can be used on SQLfiddle.com to test upon):

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    ID  integer,
    Name varchar(30),
    Mobile  varchar(20),
    Email  varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Customer (ID, Name, Mobile, Email) VALUES
    (1, 'Tim', '9876728382', 'tim@email.com'),
    (2, 'John', '9845323453', 'john@email.com'),
    (3, 'Tim', '8265748319', 'toy@test.com'),
    (4, 'John Snow', '9845323453', NULL),
    (5, 'Timmothy', '8265748319', 'timmothy@somemail.com'),
    (6, 'John', '8345908112', 'JohnySnow@someemail.com'),
    (7, 'Tim M. Jacob', NULL, 'timmothy@somemail.com'),
    (8, 'John P. Snow', '8345908112', NULL),
    (9, 'Rack', '7654783949', 'racky@email.com'),
    (10, 'Racky Dsouza', '9934364837', 'racky@email.com'),
    (11, 'Rock M. Dsouza', '9934364837', 'rackguy@somemail.com'),
    (12, 'John Snowden', '8463865392', 'John@someemail.com')
;
```

Check the below link for expected output of the SQL query. Please note that I have highlighted the values (with light yellow background) which are matching with other values of different records.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IjLfCuyKmizw0ywvDpGO_e08ATlSnlPr__UBWUsVCV0/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

The Cluster_ID assigned should preferably be same for a set of records which has one of the matching values from Name, Mobile or email.

Comment: id=9 and id=10 have a common email=`racky@email.com`. Please explain why these two id 9+10 have different cluster_id, while in a very similar case there is the same cluster id for  id=5 and i=7 which also have the same email `timmothy@somemail.com` ?

Comment: My bad! Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the sheet. Now the ID 9 and 10 have the same cluster_id.

Comment: More general solution to a similar question can be found at [How to cluster rows in a postgresql table that match an input value or match a value from any of the other matching rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239474/how-to-cluster-rows-in-a-postgresql-table-that-match-an-input-value-or-match-a-v).

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are trying to [partition of a set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) into [disjoint sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint_sets).
One idea is to partition the table using a *representative of a set*, and implement *Find( element )* function that determines a distinct set representative for a given table element (row)
see this link for details: [Disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

> One common approach is to select a fixed element of each set, called
>   its representative, to represent the set as a whole. Then, Find(x)
>   returns the representative of the set that x belongs to

---

Let say we define our *representative* of a given disjoint subset as a mimimum `ID` value of all `id` elements in this subset. This `representative value` will be our `cluster_id`
In this case the *find(x)* function could be implemented using [PostgreSQL WITH Queries (Common Table Expressions)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) in this way (the below example determines a disjoint subset representative for a row with `id = 5`):

```
with recursive xxx( id, name, mobile, email ) AS(
    select *
    from customer
    where id = 5
    union 
    select c.* 
    from customer  c
    join xxx x
    on c.name = x.name or c.mobile = x.mobile or c.email = x.email
)
select min(id) from xxx

min |
----|
1   |
```

The above query could be used as a subquery to determine set's representatives for all rows in the table, in this way:

```
select q.*,
      ( 
        with recursive xxx( id, name, mobile, email ) AS(
            select *
            from customer
            where id = q.id
            union 
            select c.* 
            from customer  c
            join xxx x
            on c.name = x.name or c.mobile = x.mobile or c.email = x.email
        )
        select min( id ) 
        from xxx
       ) as cluster_id
from customer q
order by cluster_id, id;

id |name           |mobile     |email                   |cluster_id |
---|---------------|-----------|------------------------|-----------|
1  |Tim            |9876728382 |tim@email.com           |1          |
3  |Tim            |8265748319 |toy@test.com            |1          |
5  |Timmothy       |8265748319 |timmothy@somemail.com   |1          |
7  |Tim M. Jacob   |           |timmothy@somemail.com   |1          |
2  |John           |9845323453 |john@email.com          |2          |
4  |John Snow      |9845323453 |                        |2          |
6  |John           |8345908112 |JohnySnow@someemail.com |2          |
8  |John P. Snow   |8345908112 |                        |2          |
9  |Rack           |7654783949 |racky@email.com         |9          |
10 |Racky Dsouza   |9934364837 |racky@email.com         |9          |
11 |Rock M. Dsouza |9934364837 |rackguy@somemail.com    |9          |
12 |John Snowden   |8463865392 |John@someemail.com      |12         |
```

This can work for small datasets, but if your table has many records, a speed of this query might probably be terrible.

---

Some tips how to improve this algorithm or implement a better one you can find here: [Partition refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_refinement), this most likely will require implementing an appriopriate data structure (double-linked list or arrays, depending on algorithm), SQL table is not the best choice in this case.

Comment: Thanks so much for your valuable solution. The table which I have has upwards of 5 million records, I am afraid that since the complexity is high for this approach, it might be quite costly/time consuming. Thanks for your alternate suggestion for "Partition refinement", will explore more on it.