# How to cluster rows in a postgresql table that match an input value or match a value from any of the other matching rows?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, cluster-analysis

I have a table that looks like this in my postgresql database

[image]

How can I bring back a cluster of contacts where each contact in the cluster shares either the contact_id_a or contact_id_b value (or both) with another contact in the cluster?

In the example in the screenshot image above, rows 1-6 would be in the same cluster and row 8 would belong to no cluster.

How can this be achieved using either a SQL query or a SQL query in combination with Java code?

For context, this table lists all potential duplicate contacts in a list of contacts. We want to present to the list owner all of the contacts that are potential duplicates so that the user can manually manage these duplicates.

Here is my starting code:

```
DuplicateCandidate firstDuplicate = db.sql("select * from duplicates where list_id = "+list_id+ " and ignore_duplicate is not true").first(DuplicateCandidate);
        String sql = "select * from duplicates where list_id = "+list_id+ "and ignore_duplicate is not true "
                + "and (contact_id_a = ? or contact_id_b = ? or contact_id_a = ? or contact_id_b = ?";
        List<DuplicateCandidate> groupOfDuplicates  = db.sql(sql, firstDuplicate.contact_id_a,firstDuplicate.contact_id_a, firstDuplicate.contact_id_b, firstDuplicate.contact_id_b).results(DuplicateCandidate.class);
```

This will bring back the first row and any other rows containing 16247096 or 16247097, but not other essential rows matching the contact_ids from the second query's results.

Cheers.

Comment: If identifying duplicates is the use-case, why not just `SELECT a, b, c, COUNT(1) AS d FROM table GROUP BY a, b, c HAVING d > 1`; where a, b & c are the columns on which you want to identify duplicates?

Comment: Because we are not simply searching for exact matches. We are using a scoring scheme. We've assigned each column a unique weight. We check in Java for the degree of similarity between two contacts. If the sum of the degree of similarity (using the Levenshtein distance) in each column multiplied by the corresponding column weight is below a cutoff threshold, then we consider these two contacts duplicates and add them to the table. This is too complex to be done in a SQL statement.

Comment: @GNG . . . A db/SQL fiddle would be quite helpful -- or at least data in a non-image format.

Comment: This question is in essence a duplicate of [Generate cluster field for a set of records which match the condition(s) using PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41659912/generate-cluster-field-for-a-set-of-records-which-match-the-conditions-using-p) which has a similar, but less general solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clustering like this is an iterative process with an unknown number of steps.  I have never found a solution that can be done within a recursive query.

I have not worked on CRM in over six years, but the following function is similar to how we used to generate match groups.  Doing this row-by-row did not perform well enough for our workload, and accomplishing this via host language using e.g. Java `HashMap()` and `HashSet()` and inverted indexing creates very messy code.

Assuming this schema:

```
\d contact_info 
                 Table "public.contact_info"
      Column      |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 contact_id_a     | bigint  |           |          | 
 contact_id_b     | bigint  |           |          | 
 ignore_duplicate | boolean |           |          | false
 list_id          | integer |           |          | 496

select * from contact_info ;
 contact_id_a | contact_id_b | ignore_duplicate | list_id 
--------------+--------------+------------------+---------
     16247096 |     16247097 | f                |     496
     16247096 |     16247098 | f                |     496
     16247096 |     16247099 | f                |     496
     16247097 |     16247098 | f                |     496
     16247097 |     16247099 | f                |     496
     16247098 |     16247099 | f                |     496
     16247094 |     16247095 | f                |     496
(7 rows)
```

This function creates two temp tables to hold intermediate clusters and then returns the result once there is no more clustering possible.

```
create or replace function cluster_contact() 
  returns table (clust_id bigint, contact_id bigint) 
  language plpgsql as $$
declare 
  last_count bigint := 1;
  this_count bigint := 0;
begin
  create temp table contact_match (clust_id bigint, contact_id bigint) on commit drop;
  create index cm_1 on contact_match (contact_id, clust_id);
  create index cm_2 on contact_match using hash (clust_id);
  create temp table contact_hold (clust_id bigint, contact_id bigint) on commit drop;

  with dedup as (
    select distinct least(ci.contact_id_a) as clust_id,
           greatest(ci.contact_id_b) as contact_id
      from contact_info ci
     where not ci.ignore_duplicate
  )
  insert into contact_match
    select d.clust_id, d.clust_id from dedup d
    union
    select d.clust_id, d.contact_id from dedup d;

  while last_count > this_count loop

    if this_count = 0 then 
      select count(distinct cm.clust_id) into last_count from contact_match cm;
    else 
      last_count := this_count;
    end if;

    with new_cid as (
      select cm.contact_id as clust_id_old,
             min(cm.clust_id) as clust_id_new
        from contact_match cm
       group by cm.contact_id
    )
    update contact_match
       set clust_id = nc.clust_id_new
      from new_cid nc
     where contact_match.clust_id = nc.clust_id_old;

    truncate table contact_hold;
    insert into contact_hold 
      select distinct * from contact_match;
 
    truncate table contact_match;
    insert into contact_match
      select * from contact_hold;

    select count(distinct cm.clust_id) into this_count from contact_match cm;

  end loop;

  return query select * from contact_match order by clust_id, contact_id;
end $$;
```

One of the biggest mental blocks I have seen developers face is neglecting to include the relationship of a `contact_id` to itself.  This leads to disjoint handling and a mental model needlessly complicated by a left-side and a right-side.

```
select * from cluster_contact();
 clust_id | contact_id 
----------+------------
 16247094 |   16247094
 16247094 |   16247095
 16247096 |   16247096
 16247096 |   16247097
 16247096 |   16247098
 16247096 |   16247099
(6 rows)
```

Please comment if you need clarification on any of the steps in this solution or if it does not work for you.

Also, know that Levenshtein is available in [`fuzzystrmatch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/fuzzystrmatch.html), and it works well.

If you would rather have sequential `clust_id` starting at `1`, change your `return query` in the function to this:

```
  return query 
    select dense_rank() over (order by cm.clust_id) as clust_id, 
           cm.contact_id 
      from contact_match cm 
     order by clust_id, contact_id;
```

It will yield:

```
select * from cluster_contact();
 clust_id | contact_id 
----------+------------
        1 |   16247094
        1 |   16247095
        2 |   16247096
        2 |   16247097
        2 |   16247098
        2 |   16247099
(6 rows)
```

Comment: This does seem to work. How can we change this result so that cluster_id is just an incremental integer? Or is there an advantage to having the cluster_id be the minimum contact_id in a cluster?

Comment: @GNG I used the lowest contact_id because it was there.  You can renumber it at the end using `dense_rank()`.  I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a recursive CTE.  This walks the graph and then assigns the minimum identifier in the graph for each row.  Note that your data does not have a unique identifier for each row so this starts by generating one:

```
with recursive d as (
      select row_number() over (order by contact_id_a, contact_id_b) as id, d.*
      from duplicates d
     ),
     cte (id, contact_id_a, contact_id_b, min_id, ids, lev) as (
      select id, contact_id_a, contact_id_b, id as min_id, array[id] as ids, 1 as lev
      from d
      union all
      select d.id, d.contact_id_a, d.contact_id_b, least(d.id, cte.min_id), ids || d.id, lev + 1
      from cte join
           d
           on cte.contact_id_a = d.contact_id_a or cte.contact_id_b = d.contact_id_b
      where d.id <> ALL (cte.ids)
     )
select distinct on (id) cte.*
from cte
order by id, min_id;
```

The column `min_id` contains the grouping you want.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=35517cb69a25c88596b76c465a3f2834) is a db<>fiddle illustrating the code.

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "cte"
LINE 5:       recursive cte (contact_id_a, contact_id_b, min_id, ids...
                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 141

Comment: @GNG . . . I fixed some syntax errors and added a db<>fiddle.